# "enable_annotations on the validator cannot be set as Annotations support is disabled" in symfony

Tags: symfony, annotations, symfony-3.3

I just created a bundle (successfully), and when I am about to create an entity via console this happened(also with clear:cache):

> [LogicException]
>   "enable_annotations" on the validator cannot be set as Annotations
>   support      is disabled.

mi config.yml looks like

```
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
```

when i comment the options for validation throws the same Exception but with the serializer

when i comment both then it becomes a ServiceNotFoundException

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>   The service "routing.loader" has a dependency on a non-existent
>   service "an     notation_reader".

What is the problem, I am using symfony 3.3.11

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You also need to enable annotation support in general. This happens automatically as soon as the `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation` class is present. For this, you need to make sure to install the `doctrine/annotations` package.

Comment: doctrine/annotations comes with symfony by default or not? why is happenning this? the package is in my project under vendor/doctrine/annotations

Comment: Solved! I just run an update and the problem fixed by it self. Thanks @xabbuh