# How to enable the annotation reader service for sensio framework controller listener?

Tags: symfony, annotations, symfony4

After a composer update to fix some vulnerabilities on package used by my application, I handle an error:

> The service "sensio_framework_extra.controller.listener" has a dependency on a non-existent service "annotation_reader"

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290778/enable-annotations-on-the-validator-cannot-be-set-as-annotations-support-is-dis), I tried to add the `doctrine/annotations` package, but it doesn't solved my issue (package seems to be already installed).

```
λ composer require doctrine/annotations
Using version ^1.8 for doctrine/annotations
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.2.*"
Nothing to install or update
```

Here is the packages used by my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-fileinfo": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.1",
    "ekyna/payum-monetico-bundle": "^1.5",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "payum/offline": "^1.5",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.5",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "^2.3",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
    "symfony/asset": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "1.*",
    "symfony/process": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/templating": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/translation": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.4",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "codeception/codeception": "^2.5",
    "codeception/c3": "2.*",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.14",
    "php-coveralls/php-coveralls": "^2.1",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "2.*",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.11",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.2.*"
}
```

Edit :
I'm using all the framework, I've manually dropped cache to be sure there is no problem. I rebooted my dev computer too. Finally, I went around the problem by deploying my github project in another directory and application works fine. I don't close this question because I want to find the problem if it occurs in production.

Comment: what do you mean by "deploying my project in another directory"?

Comment: I install it like a new project with: `git clone http://github.com/me/myproject.git projectCopy`

Comment: but how's your project (folder) different from before? oO

Comment: I will launch a diff between the two directories and present the diff here as soon as I detect a difference.

Answer (score 2):

since doctrine (or doctrine/annotations) itself does not register services (why would it), I looked up the doctrine bundles and the `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` provides the `annotation_reader` service: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/af8ac792c9b970ff2bc25b49ab9b31afd9e03dbf/Resources/config/orm.xml#L82

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but adding the doctrine bundle package doesn't change anything.

Comment: interesting and confusing ... are you using the framework or are you just combining the components, because this is weird ...

Comment: I'm using the framework. I edited my question to provide more information and how I went around the problem, but I would like to find the solution if problem occurs in production.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a very similar error (`The service "doctrine.orm.default_annotation_metadata_driver" has a dependency on a non-existent service "annotation_reader".`) while trying to create a new setup.  I have some instructions documented and had tried to composer install ormfixtures (--dev) before doctrine.  Once I did that in the right order, everything was working as expected.

My specific example is from Twilio's instructions, which have these commands in this order:

```
composer req --dev maker ormfixtures fakerphp/faker
composer req doctrine twig
```

It worked when I reversed them to be in this order:

```
composer req doctrine twig
composer req --dev maker ormfixtures fakerphp/faker
```

Comment: It worked for me reversing the order!

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue after a composer update from Symfony 4.4.
It was because I have replace de "Doctrine\Common" with "Doctrine" from all the using instead of "Doctrine\Common\Persistence" with "Doctrine\Persistence".

In other term: no matters why you have this error, it come from a broken namespace in your code.

This is the official link of the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html